# docker mysql replication setup

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, database-replication

Running under Mac OS X (is this easier on Ubuntu?), this is my docker compose yml file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  alpha:
    image: custom-mysql-image
    container_name: alpha
    hostname: alpha
    networks:
      groupnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.48.2
    ports:
      - '6606:3306'  # Map host port 6606 to container port 3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ["mysqld", "--loose-group-replication-local-address=alpha:6606", "--server-id=1"]
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: remoteuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
    volumes:
      - ./configs/my-cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -u remoteuser -p$${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      interval: 2s
      retries: 20

  beta:
    image: custom-mysql-image
    container_name: beta
    hostname: beta
    networks:
      groupnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.48.3
    ports:
      - '6607:3306'  # Map host port 6607 to container port 3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ["mysqld", "--loose-group-replication-local-address=beta:6606", "--server-id=2"]
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: remoteuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
    volumes:
      - ./configs/my-cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -u remoteuser -p$${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      interval: 2s
      retries: 20

  gamma:
    image: custom-mysql-image
    container_name: gamma
    hostname: gamma
    networks:
      groupnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.48.4
    ports:
      - '6608:3306'  # Map host port 6608 to container port 3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ["mysqld", "--loose-group-replication-local-address=gamma:6606", "--server-id=3"]
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: remoteuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
    volumes:
      - ./configs/my-cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -u remoteuser -p$${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      interval: 2s
      retries: 20

networks:
  groupnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.48.0/24
```

This is my-cnf file:

```
cd configs/

[mysqld]
# To be able to connect to the database via MySQL Workbench/SequelPro/other UI tools
# It is not recommended to use the mysql_native_password authentication plugin for new installations that require high password security.
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password

# Binary log file name (for data recovery after a possible MySQL server crash).
log_bin = mysql-bin-1.log

# The MySQL Server system variables described in this section are used to monitor and control Global Transaction Identifiers (GTIDs).
enforce_gtid_consistency = ON

# Controls whether GTID-based logging is enabled and what type of transactions the logs can contain.
# Enforce_gtid_consistency must be true before you can set gtid_mode=ON.
gtid_mode = ON

# Whether updates received by a replica from a replication source server should be logged to the replica's binary log.
log_slave_updates = ON

# When binlog_checksum is disabled (value NONE),
# the server verifies that it is writing only complete events to the binary log
# by writing and checking the event length (rather than a checksum) for each event.
binlog_checksum = NONE

# The setting of this variable determines whether the replica records source metadata, consisting of status and connection information,
# to an InnoDB table in the MySQL system database, or to a file in the data directory.
# Default value: TABLE
master_info_repository = TABLE

# The setting of this variable determines whether the replica server logs its position in the relay logs
# to an InnoDB table in the MySQL system database, or to a file in the data directory.
# Default value: TABLE
relay_log_info_repository = TABLE

# Load the group_replication and mysql_clone plugins at startup.
plugin-load-add = group_replication.so
plugin-load-add = mysql_clone.so

# If enabled, this variable enables automatic relay log recovery immediately following server startup.
# The recovery process creates a new relay log file, initializes the SQL thread position to this new relay log,
# and initializes the I/O thread to the SQL thread position.
relay_log_recovery = ON

# For Group Replication, transaction_write_set_extraction must be set to XXHASH64.
# The process of extracting the writes from a transaction is used in Group Replication
# for conflict detection and certification on all group members.
transaction_write_set_extraction = XXHASH64

# Whether the server should start Group Replication or not during server start.
loose_group_replication_start_on_boot = OFF

# The name of the group to which this server instance belongs.
# Must be a valid and unique UUID.
# This UUID is used internally when setting GTIDs for Group Replication events in the binary log.
loose_group_replication_group_name = aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee

# A list of group members to which a joining member can connect to obtain details of all the current group members.
# The joining member uses these details to select and connect to a group member to obtain the data needed for synchrony with the group.
# The list consists of the seed member's network addresses specified as a comma-separated list, such as host1:port1, host2:port2.
loose_group_replication_group_seeds = alpha:6606, beta:6606, gamma:6606

# Instructs the group to automatically pick a single server to be the one that handles read/write workload.
# This server is the PRIMARY, and all others are SECONDARIES.
loose_group_replication_single_primary_mode = ON

# Enables or disables strict consistency checks for multi-primary update everywhere.
# The default is that checks are disabled. In single-primary mode, this option must be disabled on all group members.
loose_group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks = OFF

# Specify relay log files and indices.
relay_log = alpha-relay-bin
relay_log_index = alpha-relay-bin.index
```

There is nothing inside the scripts directory:

```
cd scripts/
ls
```

I can bring up the containers fine:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
afc800ffcf76   custom-mysql-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes (healthy)   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6608->3306/tcp   gamma
999ae5fd4668   custom-mysql-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes (healthy)   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6607->3306/tcp   beta
d467ce670a56   custom-mysql-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes (healthy)   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6606->3306/tcp   alpha
```

However, when I try to set up mysql replication, I get errors:

```
docker exec -it alpha mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 817
Server version: 8.0.34 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> START GROUP_REPLICATION;
ERROR 3092 (HY000): The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.
mysql>
```

When I look at the logs:

```
Ivans-MacBook-Pro:configs ivan$ docker logs alpha 2>&1 | grep "ERROR" | more
2023-10-25T17:22:36.975584Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to peer node beta:6606 when joining a group. My local port is: 6606.'
2023-10-25T17:22:36.976323Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to peer node gamma:6606 when joining a group. My local port is: 6606.'
2023-10-25T17:22:36.976838Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to peer node beta:6606 when joining a group. My local port is: 6606.'
2023-10-25T17:22:36.977284Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to peer node gamma:6606 when joining a group. My local port is: 6606.'
...
```

This is my hosts file (not even sure I need it):

```
docker exec -it alpha bash
bash-4.4# cd etc
bash-4.4# cat hosts 
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.48.2    alpha
```

**I am not sure what is left to do to setup MySQL replication inside these containers?**

Comment: Sounds like a [DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's hard to say, since it mixes issues with docker and mysql so it isn't strictly db

Comment: In fact, if I had to bet the problem is with docker config, not mysql

Comment: I think Docker is incidental here. This is a MySQL replication error, not a Docker problem.